# Using error_reporting() in Zen cart

Tags: php, error-reporting, zen-cart

I am working in Zen Cart and I have some errors in different pages. I want to use `error_reporting(0)`.

How and in which page can I use this?

Could anybody please help me?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Not receive errors or not display errors? Its a good idea to leave error_reporting on, but set display_errors to 0. `ini_set( 'display_errors', 0 );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Zen cart has a built in way to make it easy to do error reporting.

Create a directory at the top of your cart called includes/local.  In this directory, put a file called configure.php.  In this file, put

```
<?php
   define('STRICT_ERROR_REPORTING', true);
   ?>
```

you will then see the php errors your code generates.

Answer (score 0):

you can just `write error_reporting(E_ALL)` for displaying all errors + notices + warnings...

Comment: "displaying" is incorrect term, however I can't find any better. But there can be not a single error displayed with E_ALL